# Unwanted characters appear in an UltiSnips macro setup

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips

I am new to vim and I am using a mac with vimtex, UltiSnips plugins.  I am using the vim latex snippets found [here](https://github.com/gillescastel/latex-snippets) (the tex.snippets file).

Whenever I type "()", "{}", the text gets automatically replaced by "()<++>" and "{}<++>" respectively. I don't know what is causing this problem. Please help.

Edit:  If I simply type "$", it gets replaced by "$$<++>".

Comment: If the users of this forum feel that this naturally fits in the TeX forum, please let me know. I can post it there. Thank you.

Comment: This fits here, no need to worry. I would *guess* that the snippets insert these markers; I’ve seen them used before as a sort of “jump to here and keep typing” placeholder.

Comment: That behavior seems to be coming from _another_ plugin... perhaps vim-latex?

Comment: @husB: Maybe yes! Do I just delete the files corresponding to that plugin? 

Actually, frustrated with the situation, I rewrote my own simple tex.snippet file. I am adding snippets as I go along.

Comment: Glad you found the problem! I recommend using a plugin manager, such as vim-plug, or even Vim 8's own package manager. These allow you to turn on specific plugins selectively. Yes, adding snippets as you go along is a good approach -- only add stuff that you need